# how to predefine an order to destroy objects on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the game I am designing is a mix between a runner and a puzzle game. The goal is simple you have to hit the cubes of the player in order to get the same shape as the square in the arch. I would like to know how to destroy in an exact order of objects here is an example. below[image: Example here]

And here is the code in which I manage my  collisions.

```
 public class Collision : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject destroyedParticle;
    public int maxHealth;
    public int currentHealth;
    Material m_Material;
    void Start()
    {
        m_Material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    void OnMouseDown()      //If the object has been clicked
    {
        if ((FindObjectOfType<Player>().ammoCount > 0) && (!FindObjectOfType<Player>().gameIsOver))     //If the player has ammo and the game is not over yet
        {
            currentHealth -= 1;
            FindObjectOfType<Player>().ammoCount -= 1; //Reduces ammo
            m_Material.color = Color.grey;
            if (currentHealth <= 0)
            {
                FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().HavocSound();      //Sound effect plays
                Destroy(Instantiate(destroyedParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity), 1f);       //Instantiates a particle and destroys it after x seconds
                Destroy(gameObject);        //Destroys the cube which has been clicked
                //FindObjectOfType<Player>().ammoCount--;     //Reduces ammo
            }    
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Obstacle"))       //If gameobject collides with an obstacle, then game is over
        {
            //Game over functions
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().DeathSound();
            Destroy(Instantiate(destroyedParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity), 1f);
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("CubeDeathAnim");
            FindObjectOfType<Player>().gameIsOver = true;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndPanelActivation();
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Animation>().Play("CameraDeathAnim");
        }
    }
        
   
}
```

I thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you specify the problem?

Comment: I would like to know how to establish a destruction order at the level of objects like show on the example but I do not see how to do

Comment: Do `Collision` class represents the rectangle or the diamond on your drawing?

Comment: yes it represents the diamond on my drawing

Answer (score 1):

You can make the object as child of an empty object and then you can specify the child id and destroy the object eg-( When player collide with the object you can use the child id to destroy the specific object)